How to create class attribute as dataframe
I wanted to pass a dataset when creating an object so that I can write methods to operate on the object and modify the dataset, e.g.
`my_obj = study.Study(one_study, a, b)
`my_obj.addDate()

I tried the following code:
`import pandas as pd
`class Study(pd1.DataFrame):`
`def __init__(self, oneStudy, m_flag, s_flag):`
       `super().__init__(oneStudy) # Inherits DataFrame properties` 
       `self.stdyData = pd1.DataFrame(oneStudy, copy=True)`
       `self.stdyData.reset_index(inplace = False, drop = True)``

and it gave:

UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name.

Also tried replacing self.stdyData = pd1.DataFrame(oneStudy, copy=True) with self.stdyData = oneStudy.copy() and got the same Pandas warning.
I tied the following as per replies in stack overflow on the same issue:
`import pandas as pd`
`class Study(pd1.DataFrame):`
`def __init__(oneStudy, m_flag, s_flag):`
       `super().__init__(oneStudy) # Inherits DataFrame properties`
       `self.stdyData = pd1.DataFrame(oneStudy, copy=True)`
       `self.stdyData.reset_index(inplace = False, drop = True)`

and the IDE complained self is not defined.
What should I do?

To answer your question this is just basic creating classes with attributes in python. There is no reason for inheritance here at all that I can see.
Example:
import pandas as pd

class Study():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

mydf = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [1,2,3]})
study = Study(mydf)

print(study.df.columns)


Thanks Topsail for the reply, it worked!! However, I cannot understand why inheritance is not needed. Since I wanted to create a new class with dataframe properties (i.e. able to use all Pandas DataFrame methods), then i think it make sense to create it as a child class of DataFrame, correct?

Its a case where you can use composition (has-a) instead of inheritance (is-a). Whether that is better or worse ... up to you there are pros and cons.
